# Writing a small yet flexible HTTP client

Tags: python, ruby, perl, http

I'm looking to find out how people would go about writing a quick (small) yet flexible HTTP client. By quick I mean not much code, (I'll leave it up to you to decide what that means), and preferably using built-in language functions as opposed to downloaded or custom libraries, such that a basic knowledge of socket programming should be sufficient to understand how the code works. By flexible I mean that you should be able to manipulate the incoming data easily. My own version of something like this would be

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Socket;
use HTML::Parse;

socket(SOCKH, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, getprotobyname('tcp')) || die $!;
connect(SOCKH,sockaddr_in(80,inet_aton('www.example.com'))) || die $!;

$old_fh = select(SOCKH);
$|=1;
select($old_fh);

print SOCKH "GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n";

while (<SOCKH>) {
    $response .= $_;
}

print parse_html($response)->format;

close(<SOCKH>);
```

This is just a quick client which I'll be editing for HTTP/1.1 shortly, or if you have suggestions on how to better it for compliancy please share!

**EDIT:** An update to my code, using LWP as Sinan Unur suggested:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::Parse;

$data = parse_html( get( 'www.example.com' ) )->format;
foreach $line ( $data ) {
    print $line; // or any other line-based operation
}
```

Comment: What is the need that is motivating this re-invention of this wheel?

Comment: Because he has an idea how to improve on the wheel?

Comment: @MkV: My need is that I want a simple skeleton for a web client that I can put together in a few minutes in future if I have a need; like a trivial program for seeing if I've any new mail in my college inbox or a bot for extracting text from a couple of web pages. I'm not trying to re-invent this "wheel", I know there are more than enough fantastic versions of this wheel already, and that's what I'm asking for.

Comment: @Greg — Wheel improvement is usually best achieved by modifying existing wheels rather than starting from scratch.

Comment: @eZanmoto — I'm confused, you know there are fantastic wheels that let you build add web client capability to an app in under a minute… so why not use one?

Comment: @David Dorward: I want to use one, but I would like to know which ones are available, how different languages approach the task, etc. My own code snippet was just to highlight how I would answer my own question using my own limited knowledge. I think by looking at my solution you can see why I asked the question.

Answer (score 9):

Perl has [LWP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/LWP). I suggest you use it.

Comment: LWP is a little less than light-weight.  HTTP::Lite (which will be used by the next release of the CPAN module) might be a better fit.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @Santa's example, only in Ruby:

```
require 'open-uri'
print open('http://www.example.com').read
```

If you want to parse the content, Ruby's [`Nokogiri`](http://nokogiri.org/) gem is awesome. It's built on top of libXML.

Many other HTTP client gems are available, including [`HTTParty`](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) and [`Typhoeus`](https://github.com/pauldix/typhoeus). HTTParty makes it trivial to add REST capability to a class, along with the ability to parse JSON and XML. Typhoeus makes it easy to write multiple requests all at once for parallel gets/heads/whatevers.

Answer (score 2):

Python has "batteries included"

You don't need to work at the socket level (although you can).  Python has several higher level web/http libraries built in its standard library.

for example, in Python 2, you can use [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html):

```
import urllib2

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com/')
html = response.read()
```

also check out [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html), for slightly lower level access:

```
>>> import httplib
>>> conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.python.org")
>>> conn.request("GET", "/index.html")
>>> r1 = conn.getresponse()
>>> print r1.status, r1.reason
200 OK
>>> data1 = r1.read()
>>> conn.request("GET", "/parrot.spam")
>>> r2 = conn.getresponse()
>>> print r2.status, r2.reason
404 Not Found
>>> data2 = r2.read()
>>> conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib

f = urllib.urlopen('http://www.example.com')
print f.read()
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of examples seem trivial until you start needing to do anything heavy, like streaming gigabytes of data in both directions. My favorite is ruby's `net/http`, which is part of every ruby install.

Here's an example that streams the data, and leaves the connection open when you're finished for more requests.

```
require 'net/http'

http = Net::HTTP.new('my.server.org')
http.start

req = Net::HTTP::Post.new('/path/to/huge/file')
req.basic_auth('user', 'pass')
req.content_length = File.size 'huge_input_file.txt'
req.body_stream = File.open('huge_input_file.txt', 'rb')

http.request(req){|res|
  File.open('huge_output_file.txt', 'wb'){|f|
    res.read_body {|chunk| f.write chunk}
  }
}
```

---

Perl doesn't have anything built-in. `Net::HTTP` and `LWP::UserAgent` are not part of perl core. A while back I needed a perl http client that functions like the above ruby example, without depending on anything from CPAN. It took under 200 lines, using only `IO::Socket::INET` and `syswrite`/`sysread` (which eliminates a lot of the lower-layer socket nonsense), and `MIME::Base64` for authentication.

Comment: File::Fetch is included into core Perl, HTTP::Lite can be easily bundled.

Comment: Huh. File::Fetch was added in 5.10? Cool! +1 for that tidbit

Comment: @Alexandr Ciornii: File::Fetch is not very useful. it cannot even fetch a simple home page: `File::Fetch->new(uri => 'http://www.google.com/');`

Answer (score 1):

I take it that you don't actually want to write your own http client, but rather a script that fetches stuff using http?

Others mentioned [HTTP::Lite](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP%3a%3aLite) and [LWP::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP%3a%3aSimple) ..

Here's an example using [Mojo::Client](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mojo%3a%3aClient), from the docs.

```
# Quick JSON request
my $trends = 'http://search.twitter.com/trends.json';
print $client->get($trends)->res->json->{trends}->[0]->{name};

# Extract data from HTML and XML resources
print $client->get('mojolicious.org')->res->dom->at('title')->text;

# Scrape the latest headlines from a news site
my $news = 'http://digg.com';
$client->max_redirects(3);
$client->get($news)->res->dom('h3 > a.story-title')->each(sub {
    print shift->text . "\n";
});
```

Cool, but not the most mature module available..

Comment: Yeah, mojo isn't mature, but it's pretty cool, as is mojolicious.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what possible benefit you would get from any answers to such a question, but I'll give in to the peer pressure. Since you don't seem to bothered which language to use...

If you want to manipulate it in interesting ways:

```
<?php
$d=new DOMDocument();
$d->loadHTMLFile('http://www.example.com/');
...
```

But to just return a page:

```
<?php
print file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
```

Comment: I have stated the benefit I'd get: "My need is that I want a simple skeleton for a web client that I can put together in a few minutes in future if I have a need" and "I would like to know which [solutions to the problem] are available, how different languages approach the task".